# Возврат в исходный контроллер UINavigationController

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, navigationbar, navigationcontroller

Интересует механизм возврата в исходный `TableViewController` под управлением `UINavigationController`.

Суть в том, что есть главный `TableViewController` со статичными ячейками, который исполняет роль меню, а так же есть два `ViewController` - `oneVC` и `twoVC`

Требуется сделать так, что бы в `OneVC` при нажатии кнопки открывался `twoVC` и наоборот. Основная загвоздка в том, что в `NavigationBar` при нажатии кнопки "назад" из любого контроллера возвращаться на главный `TableViewController`, а не на предыдущее окно.

Возможно ли как то оформить такой переход?

Answer (score 1):

Такое поведение происходит потому-что вы вызываете `twoVC` методом `self.present(twoVC, animated: true, completion: nil)`
 - т.е. модально.

Чтобы иметь возможность возвращаться в предыдущие контроллеры вы должны использовать метод `navigationController?.pushViewController(twoVC, animated: true)` который вставляет в навигационный стек ваш новый контроллер.

С помощью методов `UINavigationController` вы можете управлять контроллерами в стеке.

Например метод `navigationController?.viewControllers` вернет вам массив контроллеров которые находятся в навигационном стеке.

**UPD:**

Переопределяете кнопку назад и используете необходимый метод.

`func popToRootViewController(animated: Bool)` - pop на главный (самый первый) контроллер.

`func popToViewController(UIViewController, animated: Bool)` - pop на необходимый контроллер.

Comment: Так мне надо вернуться не в предыдущий oneVC например, а в исходное меню TableVC

Comment: и я вызываю переход через инспектор, а не кодом

Comment: @IvanKisin Тогда нужно посмотреть в сторону  Unwind Segue